# Is there any function to extract the text which has a specific heading from pdf

Tags: python, pdf, text-mining

I have multiple paragraphs in my pdf document. Each paragraph has a unique Heading to it. How can I extract the text from the pdf under a specific heading that I am looking for

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use PyPDF2 python library for that, sample snippets :

```
# importing required modules
import PyPDF2

# creating a pdf file object
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb')

# creating a pdf reader object
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

# printing number of pages in pdf file
print(pdfReader.numPages)

# creating a page object
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)

# extracting text from page
print(pageObj.extractText())

# closing the pdf file object
pdfFileObj.close()
```